# not able to do indexing of salesforce Knowledge via third party integration---"Coveo For Salesforce"

Tags: knowledge, coveo

not able to do indexing of salesforce Knowledge via third party integration---"Coveo For Salesforce" after migration of Knowledge articles From Classic to Lightning.[image]

Here in attached screenshot the Salesforce Knowledge is showing  indexing for very long time.
May be its because of earlier ,Knowledge articles are categorised as seperate article types in CLASSIC,
But after migrating into Lightning the Article Types are now record types under "Knowledge" object.
And this package has been installed before Knowledge Lightning Migration.
What can be the possible reason this thiord party search package unable to index the salesforce Knowledge article????

Comment: Why not? Can you be more specific? What have you tried? What errors do you get? We need more information to adequately help you. Please [edit] your question to include more information.

Comment: Edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually have to go to the Coveo Admin UI and manually select the object "knowledge" that you want to index and then trigger a rebuild.

This is one of the pitfalls when migrating to lightning knowledge when using Coveo, you have to reconfigure your source, however, the admin UI should facilitate this.